# JAVAFX Determining which label has been clicked

Tags: javafx, event-handling, label, fxml

I haven't found a solution here on SO I could use so I'll hope there's someone here who will find a minute to help me. I'm making my first app in javafx to learn how the things work here...and:

By fx:define, in my fxml file I defined a labelList, which basically consists of all the player names who are ingame. It contains 10 labels, but in case there are just 4 players, only 4 labels are set visible so that's why in this loop below I use playerList.size().

By clicking on a label, I want my app to be able to determine which label has been clicked. So I can get the id of the player to use it in other functions (for example, I pick one label then click on a button which adds points to the player with the same id as the label).

I managed to do this without the loop and it works perfectly:

```
labelList.get(0).setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
              @Override
              public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                  labelList.get(0).setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
                  setId(0);
              }
            });
```

But I've been wondering if it's possible to do this at once, in a loop. From bigger perpective, if there were many more labels and other stuff, it would look really horrible to look at the code with 50 handlers started separately. If I try to run this loop, I get error stating "Local variable is defined in 
an enclosing scope must be final"

```
@FXML
private void activatePlayer() {

    for( int id = 0; id < playerList.size(); id++) { 
        labelList.get(id).setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
              @Override
              public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                  labelList.get(id).setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
                  setId(id);
              }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered several times on this site, but my quick search can't find equivalent answers.

Just put the id (and the label, if you like) in a (effectively) final variable:

```
for( int id = 0; id < playerList.size(); id++) { 
    Label label = labelList.get(id);
    int currentId = id ;
    label.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            label.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
            setId(currentId);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time!